# How to push from one bare git repo to another?

Tags: git, version-control, github

Me and a couple of other guys from a big team are working on a separate page on the project. Let's call it groups page. While we work on the groups page, we need to exchange incomplete code, the code we wouldn't want to be sent to the central repo. And during this time, we also work on features not related to groups page, we do need to commit and push to the central server. I am looking at solutions for this problem, here are my ideas. Please comment on them.

We can't make a branch in the actual repo server because of the higher ups.

1. Create and email diffs to each other, then lose changes and use the diff when we need to go back to groups page. The person getting the emails applies the diff. etc.
2. We make a change to our code, commit it, but don't push it. Then whoever needs that incomplete code, can pull from us directly.
3. Make another clone of the central server with --bare flag. So we can treat it as a local-central server just for the groups page. We can pull from it and create a separate workspace for groups page. We can push and pull to it.

Now each of these has problems.

1. is too tedious. I wanna use git for it.
2. When someone has pulled from me, and then worked on a new feature, and then he pushes (to the central server), then whatever he pulled from me doesn't get pushed to the server. How would he finally push it to the server when our groups page code is complete.
3. The same problem. Is there a way I push from this local-central server to the main server? Both are bare repos of course. Is there a way to push from one bare clone to the main github repo?

Comment: You could make a free private git repo on bitbucket, add that repo to your remotes, then commit/push up to your github repo master whenever needed. This seems very odd, though. Why aren't you doing branches with pull requests on your github repo?

Comment: Let's just say I am not allowed to. If I do as you say, would I be able to push changes from that bit bucket repo to my master, in the end?

Comment: You wouldn't be pushing directly from bitbucket. You'd use that repo to collaborate with your team. You'd all make changes, push those changes to bitbucked, pull down those changes to your local repo (your machine), then push up to your github master from your local repo. Make sense?

Comment: The simplest solution (assuming some unstated constraint doesn't prevent it) is to push the work to the central repo, just not to the master branch. About the only thing needed to make that work in practice is for people not on your group to just ignore branches they don't "own". A number of git servers even have access controls that allows enforcing that. -- If there is a need to **prevent** others from seeing the WIP... well at that point I'd start to question the requirements and processes; there are few good reasons for doing that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

3 is your best option. In fact, that's really how Git is intended to be used; with repositories for individual components, which feed into a more central repository when work is done.

There is no problem pushing someone else's changes. Lets say you make a change, and push it to the groups page repository. Then I pull that, make some changes, and push them back. Now we decide we're done. If I push to the central repository, that push will include both my changes, and your changes which my changes were based on.

You do not need to push from one bare repo to another. Git works by pushing from your local repo, to one or more remote repos. When you clone, there's a default remote repo called "origin". But you can have as many remote repos configured as you want. To set this up, let's say you have cloned from the central repo; that's called "origin". Now you create a bare repo: it's at `ssh://some-machine.corp.com/path/to/groups-repo.git`. In your local working repo, just do `git remote add groups ssh://some-machine.corp.com/path/to/groups-repo.git`, and you will have a reference to that groups repo. Now you can use `git fetch`, `git pull`, `git push` and so on with `groups` as well as with `origin`.

Comment: let me say that again just to make sure I understood you. 

There is a master (github) where we are all pulling from and pushing to. We keep using this for our 'usual' coding. 

On another machine, we make a bare clone of master, let's call it groups. Then on our machines, we clone from this machine, in a different work space. So now we have two different. For all the coding related to groups page, we push to and pull from groups machine to our groups work space. When our work is complete, one guy pulls from groups machine, and pushes it to github, by the process you just mentioned.

Comment: @Caffeine Almost got it. The one trick is that you don't need to clone into a different workspace. You can just create multiple remotes in a single workspace; you can use a local branch which tracks the "groups/master", and another which tracks "origin/master", and switch between them whenever you want with `git checkout`. You can use multiple workspaces if you want to, but it's really convenient sometimes to have one workspace with multiple remotes. And yeah, when you are done doing development, someone who has pulled the latest code from the groups machine can push it up to the main repo.

Comment: I would never need to merge those branches, right? Being on the groups-branch, after pushing the final changes to github remote, I can just delete this branch. And when I will do pull on the main branch on my machine, the group-changes will be added to it since they were pushed to github?

Comment: @Caffeine Right, once you have merged the groups branch into the main github branch, you don't need to keep the groups branch (or repository) around; the full history will now be in the github repo. And yep, once the changes have been pushed to the github repo, if you pull from that, ou will get all of the changes.

Comment: No, I meant. What if I never merge the branches on my machine. The thing is, the sub-team working on the groups page isn't really fluent with git :) I want the most convenient way of doing things, even if it's not much efficient.

Comment: @Caffeine You don't need to merge the branches while you are working, that's right. You can all work on the groups branch, entirely independently of the main work, and then at the end, one person can check out the main branch, do `git merge groups/master` or `git merge group-branch`, and then push to the main repo. You will have to do a merge (or pull, which is a shorthand for "fetch then merge") at some point, if there were commits to both the main repo and the groups repo; if the only work was happening on the groups repo, then no, you don't need to merge, you can just push it directly over.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to push from one bare clone to the main github repo?

Yes, you don't have to be in a work tree to push changes from a bare repo.

Simply ssh to the place where you 'local master' is, and run:

```
git push origin master
```

As the other answer point out, you can also push directly from your local copy to a remote master, but it's sometimes more convenient to have an automated 'gatekeeper' repository like this that can be triggered to push changes out (eg. after review) to multiple remote repositories via automation, without worrying about setting up ssh keys and so forth for a specific individual to push the changes out.

Comment: Could you help to comment how to pull from the remote master to the local master ? `git pull origin master` complains "This operation must be run in a work tree"

Comment: @SOUser, `git fetch`.

Answer (score 2):

To make it simple, Git is a **distributed** version control system. This mean that whenever you clone from a repo, you clone **the entire** repository. And each clone is completely independent. In fact, what you clone on your machine is exactly the same as what's on the server, your clone can receive push/pull, etc. (*Only difference is probably that you won't let anybody connect in via ssh*)

So, whichever way you go, if your coworkers pull from you, they can push your commit to the main repo. Same thing will apply with option 3, use your team git server, and when ready, some of you pull to his machine and push from there to the main server.

So, in your case, option 3 would be the easiest. Although, once you push to the main repo, this repo will gave all the work you've done in your private server. So, I'm not even sure it's really useful for you to have your own server (unless you want to make sure nobody else touch your "private" branch).