# How to connect my local server git repository with remote repository (Adobe cloud git repository)?

Tags: git, repository, aem, windows-server, git-remote

I have create a Git repository on my local server where we will commit & push our changes through eclipse.Further, we want to connect with  this local server git repository with our remote git repository (Adobe cloud git repository). I can successfully commit and push changes from my local machine to local server git repository. Now my this server repository looks like this as it stores data in packs. 
[image]

I can also pull changes from another machine. Now I need to connect this local server with my remote repository so that we can push changes their. Can you please help me what commands I need to give ? I have tried to explore this but it is quite confusing. So kindly help in this regard.

Comment: I don't think you can push from one repository to another one, however you can push to several git repositories from your local machine. This is what I do at home, I have a local server where I push my changes for testing and I can also push to a remote server for production

Comment: Why would you do this? Wouldn't it make more sense to just use different branches on the central server? As far as I know the Adobe cloud build chain has different stages as well, so why would you like to have another repository?

Comment: Actually, we do not want  to keep committing to cloud unless it was the final deployment. Therefore, we want our local git server repository

Comment: Your local server has a bare repository? Perhaps a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13373617/5784831)?

Comment: Yes. Once, we have committed our changes to local server repository, we want to sync these changes to remote git repository in Adobe Cloud.